# Sql - order by number of conditions satisfied

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a query with multiple conditions that are in the OR relation like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE (c1) OR (c2) OR (c3) OR ...
```

I do not want results to be ordered based on the number of condition they satisfied .this means records that satisfied c1 and c2 and c3 showed first(3 conditions),then the  records that satisfy c1 and c2,or c1 and c3 ,or c2 and c3(2 conditions) and at the end records that satisfy c1 or c2 or c3

Comment: maybe You could use Union for this? Select every records with 1 condition and Union it after?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make an expression that looks like this:

```
( CASE WHEN c1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN c2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN c3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

It will provide you the number of conditions satisfied by the current record.

Comment: Or (c1) + (c2) + (c3).

Comment: So how would this be used in a full query?

Comment: @FrankyBoy Just like any other condition in SQL `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY (CASE WHEN c1 THEN ... ELSE 0 END) DESC`

Comment: right, thanks ... brainfart I guess :D ... actually I added it as a column now (so I'd get a "weight" in the response which I can then process further).